# Why this expression in angular js don't show anything?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learning angular, but there is some examples who don't work at all (i am using version 4.7).

Here:

```
            <div ng-app="direttive" ng-controller="addizione">
                <b>Ng-bind result addiction by two model</b><br/><br/>
                Numero1 = <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.numerouno" min="0" max="99" required><br/>
                Numero2 = <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.numerodue" min="0" max="99" required><br/>
                <p>addizione:  {{example.numerouno}}</p>
            </div>
                angular.module('direttive',[]);
                .controller('addizione', ['$scope',function($scope){
                $scope.example = {
                    numerouno: 12
                    numerodue: 7
                };
            }]);
```

when i try to visualize using browser i don't see any number or wxpression, should someone tell me where i am wrong please?

Comment: Where's the expression? Are you trying to add two numbers?

Comment: You will 100% see a javascript error (or 2!) in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want sum of two field.
Please check this:
HTML

```
 <div ng-app="direttive" ng-controller="addizione">
 <b>Ng-bind result addiction by two model</b><br/><br/>
 Numero1 = <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.numerouno" min="0" max="99" required><br/>
 Numero2 = <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.numerodue" min="0" max="99" required><br/>
 <p>addizione:  {{total}} </p></div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('direttive', []);
app.controller('addizione', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){

$scope.example = {"numerouno": 12, "numerodue": 7};

$scope.total = $scope.example.numerouno + $scope.example.numerodue;}]);
```

codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYzOOZ

Comment: It's generally useful to explain *what* you've changed (and *why* you've changed it) rather than just post a working version!

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('direttive',[]);
                    .controller('addizione', ['$scope',function($scope){
```

Remove `;` from module becuase `controller` is directly binding to it.

```
angular.module('direttive',[])
                .controller('addizione', ['$scope',function($scope){
```

Another is

```
$scope.example = {
                    numerouno: 12
                    numerodue: 7
                };
```

Use `,` for multiple key and value for object.

```
$scope.example = {
    numerouno: 12,
    numerodue: 7
  };
```

Check working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/br6nj57j/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon at the end of `angular.module('direttive',[]);` and it would work.